# Spectral decomposition

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

For a compact normal operator, the space can be written as the sum of generalized eigenspaces. So every element can be written as a linear combination of the eigenvectors, one from each eigenspace. But an eigenspace may have more than one linearly independant eigenvector so does this say 2 (linearly independent) eigenvectors from the same eigenspace cannot be involved in the same linear combination?

Thanks

Comment: Your statement "So every element can be written as a linear combination of the eigenvectors, one from each eigenspace." is incorrect. If the dimension of the eigenspace is N>1 then it contains N independent vectors (which may be taken orthogonal) and each is required in an expansion of your element. Of course some (or all) of the coefficients may vanish.

Comment: Ok I agree with that. So how can the space be wriiten as a direct sum of the eigenspaces, which demand we take only ONE eigenvector from each eigenspace?

Comment: See my answer for the mathematical details.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be the operator in question. Its spectral decomposition is $$K=∑_{n}λ_{n}P_{n},$$
where $P_{n}$ is the eigenprojector associated with the eigenvalue $λ_{n}$. It is finite dimensional and we can write $$P_{n}=∑_{j_{n}}P_{j_{n}}$$
with the $P_{j_{n}}$ a finite set of one-dimensional orthogonal projectors. Hence $$K=∑_{n}∑_{j_{n}}λ_{n}P_{j_{n}}$$